# set midnight in javascript for cookie expiration

Tags: javascript, date, gettime

Good morning, I currently have this script:

```
now = new Date (). getTime ();
now = now + 86400000;
```

this takes the current date and time and adds 24 hours to it.

Instead, I would need to set midnight of the current day. I tried with:

```
var d = new Date ();
date = d.setHours (0,0,0,0);
now = date / 1000;
```

but it does not work! I need this to set the expiration of a cookie:

```
$ .cookies.set ('mycookie2250', 'true', {expiresAt: new Date (now)});
```

in the first case it works but in the second it doesn't.
Where am I wrong?

Comment: it would help if you had a look at the Date library, particularly `setHours()` and so on https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/setHours

Comment: Why are you dividing the date by 1000? You already have the date in milliseconds you can directly create a date object with it.

Comment: Define "does not work". `d.setHours(0,0,0,0)` gets local midnight at the start of the day. If you want the end of the day (i.e. midnight at the start of tomorrow), then `d.setHours(24,0,0,0)` does the trick.

Comment: I did it divided by 1000 because doing some research I had seen this example.
Sorry but I'm not an expert.
Now I have tried:
var date = new Date ();
date.setHours (0,0,0,0);
and that's correct because it takes me midnight today.
But I believe there is still a problem with writing the cookie.
I tried both like this (i.e. as it was originally):
$.cookies.set ('mycookie2250', 'true', {expiresAt: new Date (date)});
that like this:
$.cookies.set ('mycookie2250', 'true', {expiresAt: date});

Comment: I think I understand my problem ...
As indicated by @RobG I was using d.setHours (0,0,0,0)
but this is the beginning of the day so a time has already passed.
This is why the cookie is not written.
I have to use precisely: d.setHours (24,0,0,0)

Answer (score 0):

```
var date = new Date();
date.setHours(0,0,0,0);

// date is midnight.
```

Comment: Thanks but I have two doubts:
1) the +1 I see in the line:
date.setDate (date.getDate () + 1);
takes me the date tomorrow. I need today's one so I guess just remove it.
2) do I no longer have to divide by 1000?

Comment: You are correct, I removed that line in my answer. Why do you need to divide by 1000? `date` is the object. If you want to get unixtime `ms` just do `.getTime()`, otherwise do `.getTime() / 1000`. However, since it's for a cookie, you can just convert the date to UTC by doing `date.toISOString()`